# html <object data> using a non link to navigate to a page I click on from a page with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, php, html

Right now I have 4 search pages being pulled into one page using a table and the object tag. If I click on a link anywhere with anyone of the search pages I can go to that link.

How can I go to that systems home page by clicking in an area without a link? For instance I can click on anything at Google.com and even insert my cursor into the search area, but I would like to click it so it is the only page on the screen too.

I don't want to lose the functionality of being able to click on links when multiple webpages are up..

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="height:800px">
            <object data='http://google.com' width='100%' height='100%'>
            </object>
        </td>
        <td style="height:800px">
            <object data='http://bing.com' width=100% height='100%'>
                <pr>Browser won't retrieve the forecast</pr>
            </object>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:800px">
            <object data='http://lycos.com' width=100% height='100%'>
            </object>
        </td>
        <td style="height:800px">
            <object data='http://ask.com' width=100% height='100%'>
            </object>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is it needed to use object tag? You can store your url in a data attribute by using simply a div and you can add a simple click eventhandler to it. When you click on it just get the stored url from the data and give it to the window.location.